# Print Composer Template produces empty map?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, print-composer

I have a **print composer template** which I'm trying to populate with different subset queries from a CSV-derived vector layer using the **Python** API. However, all the output PDFs contain everything **except the layers on the map**! I'm doing this with a **standalone app**, and it functions fine in that it does produce PDFs and the data is all loaded and interrogated just fine (I can subset query, count features etc.)

Here's the method I'm using to render the composition, as you can see I've tried to **set the layers** on the map in different places (actually there are 2 maps - one shows the extent rectangle of the other, but I can't get either to show anything) - this is my first QGIS scripting experience so I'm sure I'm missing something very obvious...

```
def compose(layers, species_binomial):
    # vlayer is the CSV vector layer, outline is the ADM0 country vector.
    vlayer, outline = layers

    # construct a QStringList for the renderer setLayerSet
    layers = QStringList(vlayer.id())
    layers.append(outline.id())

    # 1 maybe set the registry layers???
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(outline)

    # 2 maybe set the canvas layer???
    canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
    canvas.setExtent(outline.extent())
    canvas.setLayerSet([QgsMapCanvasLayer(outline), QgsMapCanvasLayer(vlayer)])

    # 3 set the renderer layers???
    renderer = canvas.mapRenderer()
    renderer.setLayerSet(layers)
    renderer.setExtent(outline.extent())

    composition = QgsComposition(renderer)
    with open(os.path.join(ROOT, 'species_composer.qpt'), 'rt') as fp:
        composer_template = fp.read()
    doc = QDomDocument()
    doc.setContent(composer_template)
    composition.loadFromTemplate(doc)

    # 4 maybe set the map layers of one of the maps???
    map1 = composition.composerMapItems()[1]
    map1.setLayerSet(layers)

    title = composition.getComposerItemById('title')
    title.setText(" ".join(species_binomial))  # this works fiiiine

    out_path = os.path.join(ROOT, 'out',  "%s_%s.pdf" % species_binomial)

    # make a lovely blank PDF with a title and a blue map rect
    ...
```

What am I doing wrong? Here's an example output...

[image: PDF output from print composer template]

Comment: I have the same doubt. Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you opening the project file you used to produce the map composer template you are using?

Comment: @Steve Pike Did you ever figure this one out? I think I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, you need to set two things First, we need to zoom to layer extent and set the crs of the layer to layout Finally, we need to refresh the map item and layout you can get detail explination https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.28/core/QgsLayoutItemMap.html#qgis.core.QgsLayoutItemMap

```
# zoom the extent map item's extent based on the layer extent
    
    map_item.zoomToExtent(layer_extent)
    map_item.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(crs))
    map_item.refresh()
    layout.refresh()
```